# What do the blue flags represent?

Tags: godus

Shortly after building a hut, a blue flag with a white stripe on it will appear. This flag is clickable, and clicking upon it causes the villager in the hut to leave.

[image]

What is actually happening here? Is my population increasing? Am I evicting the believer from their home?

What do the blue flags represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blue flags signify a usable member of your population.

Clicking on the house with the blue flag will cause a citizen to pop out and, if there's a plot of land ready for building (nearby), start building. If there isn't a plot of land ready, they will enjoy the scenery. Or maybe die. They do that sometimes too.

Comment: Does this mean that I shouldn't just be clicking on the flags the moment they appear then?

Comment: That I cannot say. I will research it more, but I think they die faster if you use them more without rejuvenating them. I'll see what I can find out!

Comment: Only pop the person if you have a job for them. Otherwise they will wander about a bit, and eventually die. When they die, you lose belief.